# Flex 3: Is there an easy way to change a value within a component from within the main application?

Tags: apache-flex, module, components, autosuggest

So I'm using a custom auto suggest component that I found online at http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/.  The background color for the item is set within the following folder: com > hillelcoren > components > autoComplete > FlowBox.mxml.  The bg color hard coded in there to be white:

```
<mx:Canvas
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns="com.hillelcoren.components.autoComplete.classes.*"
    verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
    borderStyle="inset" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    initialize="init()" clipContent="true" 
    xmlns:components="com.hillelcoren.components.*">
```

I use this component from within a component I created called "position.mxml" that is located in a folder named "modules".  Is there any way that from the position module, I can change the background color of the autosuggest box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it depends on the component architecture and I have no drilled into the architecture of Hillel's AutoComplete component.

Styles are often inherited, so in theory setting the backgroundColor style on the position component or on the AutoComplete is one way to set the value.,  However, I would expect a "hard coded" style to override such inheritance unless you set it after the component initialized.

Another approach is to modify Hillel's component to expose this value as a style.  In theory this isn't that hard; in practice a complicated architecture could make it difficult. [More info on creating custom styles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf687e7-7ff6.html).

A third approach is to drill down into the component and set the style.  Something like this:

```
positionInstance.autoCompleteInstance.flowBoxInstance.setStyle('backgroundColor',myNewStyle);
```

Of course, all the relevant component instances must be public to do so.

A fourth approach might be to use a different component.  [The Flextras AutoComplete](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19) component is a native Spark component and it would be easy to create a custom skin that changes the background color of any of the relevant skin parts.

Comment: Can the flextras autocomplete change bg color based on a boolean value that changes quite often while the application is being used?

Comment: @Brds Styles you set on the component class are inherited in the skin class; so you could easily mock something up with a custom skin class.  I'm pretty sure that the skin class's styleChanged() method will fire when a style is set in the component class; and that is where you could do the toggling.  None of this is unique to our component, though, it's just how the framework operates.